# Somehow i am unable to override normalize.css?

Tags: html, css, normalize

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKMwz.png)
[CSS code](https://pastebin.com/8RsrPBn8)

I am beginner , somehow i am unable to remove the margins from h1 element. I Don't know what the problem is.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/grid.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Omnifood</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="hero-text-box">
      <h1>Goodbye junk food. Hello super healthy meals.</h1>
      <a href="#">I’m hungry </a>
      <a href="#">Show me more </a>
    </div>
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

re-order your link tags as below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css"> <!-- reset default styling -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/grid.css"> <!-- add grid support -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/css/style.css"> <!-- apply custom styles to your code -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You can re-order the `style.css` to be after `normalize.css`, or you can use `!important` to force the CSS:

```
h1 {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Three possible solutions here:

1- In your HTML, include `normalize.css` first, and then the other CSS files that will override it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/grid.css">
```

2- You can override style properties from `normalize.css` by using more precise selectors in your `style.css` file. For example, assume that your `h1` is in a div with class `container`, you can do:

```
.container h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

As `.container h1` is more precise than the `h1` selector in `normalize.css`, the property will be overridden automatically.

3- If neither of these work for you, you can use `!important` to force the margin property to be overridden, like so:

```
h1 {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First reorder your resource files and simply use below in your css. Make note of the ***px*** part.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/css/style.css">
```

CSS Code

```
h1 {
  margin: 0px;
}
```